# CakePhp 3.5: save other data in beforeDelete() which returns false

Tags: cakephp, orm, behavior, cakephp-3.x

I am implementing a *ReviewableBehavior* to implement a four eyes principle. The behavior implements `beforeDelete()`, `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()` and uses a *reviews* table to store CUD requests.

1. for added records, a `$review` record is created and saved in `afterSave()` (because only the we have the id of the newly added record, which we need to store in the `$review`)
2. for edited records, in `beforeSave()` the values that have been changed are saved in a `$review` record, in the edited record these field values are set back to their original values (so basically no changes are saved)
3. for deleted records, in `beforeDelete()` a `$review` is saved to store the delete request, and false is returned in order to cancel the delete

Number 3. is the challenge, because although `$review` always had a correctly set primary key value as if the save was actually successful, and `save($review)` returned true as if everything went well, it was not actually saved in the database.

The reason, as far as I understand: Deletions are by default done within a transaction. The transaction is started in `delete()` of the table, then `beforeDelete()` of the behavior is triggered. With in the event handler, I call `ReviewTable->save($review)`. As a transaction has been started, this `save()` happens within the transaction. Then I return false, because I want the deletion to be stopped. This rolls back the transaction and with it the `ReviewTable->save($review)`.

Solution attempts:

- If I do not return false, the `$review` is saved in the database, but the "main" record is also deleted. Disadvantage: Not a feasible approach as record is deleted which we do not want.
- If I call `delete($entity, ['atomic' => false]);` then there is no transaction started, hence `ReviewTable->save($review)` is executed. Disadvantage: For any model that uses this behavior, we would need to amend every call to `delete()` to switch the atomic of. Also this switches the use of transactions off, which does not appear a good approach to me.
- "Overwrite" delete method in *ReviewableBehavior*, so for any table using this behavior, when `delete()` is called, actually the `delete()` of the _ReviewableBehavior_is performed. Disadvantage: technically not possible to overwrite table methods with a behavior.

  - Create a new table class, overwrite `delete()` method in it, and derive any table using the *ReviewableBehavior* from the table class. Disadvantage: ugly approach having to use both the behavior and a new table class.
  - Create a new method `deleteRequest()` in the *ReviewableBehavior*, and instead of calling `Table->delete()` we call `Table->deleteRequest()`. In it, we can save the delete request in a `$review` record, deletion is not done anyway as we did not actually call `delete()`. Disdavantage: For any model that uses this behavior, we would need to change every call to `delete()` into `deleteRequest()`

Currently I go with the last approach, but I would really like to hear some opinions about this, and also whether there is any better method to somehow keep the transaction, but saving something "in between".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a separate method is a sensible approach. Another option might be to circumvent the deletion process by stopping the `Model.beforeDelete` event, when doing so you can return `true` to indicate a successful delete operation, ie no rollback will happen.

It should be noted that stopping the event will cause possible other listeners in the queue to not be notified! Also halting the regular deletion process will prevent  cascading deletes (ie deleting associated records), and the `Model.afterDelete` event, so if you need cascading deletes, then you'd need to trigger them manually, and the `afterDelete` event should usually be triggered for successful deletes in any case.

Here's a quick and dirty example, see also **[`\Cake\ORM\Table::_processDelete()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/source-class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#2315-2374)** for insight on how the regular deletion process works:

```
public function beforeDelete(
    \Cake\Event\Event $event,
    \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity,
    \ArrayObject $options
) {
    // this will prevent the regular deletion process
    $event->stopPropagation();

    $table = $event->getSubject();

    // this deletes associated records
    $table->associations()->cascadeDelete(
        $entity,
        ['_primary' => false] + $options->getArrayCopy()
    );

    $result = /* create review record */;
    if (!$result) {
        // this will cause a rollback
        return false;
    }

    $table->dispatchEvent('Model.afterDelete', [
        'entity' => $entity,
        'options' => $options,
    ]);

    return true;
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Defining Event Listeners](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#defining-event-listeners)**
- **[Cookbook > Events > Stopping Events](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#stopping-events)**